# Unique entries in Notification Center and 'repeatInterval'

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, push-notification

I'm issuing a local notification alert (iOS 5) that will repeat its reminder periodically (every minute) until the user acknowledges it by setting `repeatInterval` on the `UILocalNotification` instance added to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:`

The effect of setting 'repeatInterval' is that each time the notification is repeated while not acknowledging it, there's another entry in the Notification Center. e.g: After 5 minutes of not ack'ing the firing, there are 5 separate entries in the Notification Center.

Is there way to only have one entry, but sound/vibrate alert every 1 minute?

Here's how I'm creating the local notification:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotify = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotify.fireDate = aFireDate;
localNotify.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotify.userInfo = userInfo;

// 3. Configure the substance of the notification: alert, icon badge number, and sound.
localNotify.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(alertTitleText, nil);                            
localNotify.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(alertActionText, nil);

localNotify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

localNotify.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

// Schedule the local notification for delivery.    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotify];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. As long as the user has Notification Center turned on for your app, every local notification you fire will show up as a distinct entry in Notification Center; even if they are multiple firings of the same UILocalNotification object. The [UILocalNotification API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3) gives you no control over this.